# How to filter database record by a IList in EF

Tags: entity-framework, select, filter, ilist

The db contains product and color table with a many-to-many relation.
So, The product has an `IList<Colors>` attribute.
For example, I create an `IList` that contains two `colors` and I want get the `products` that this `Colors` contains other `IList`.
Is that possible or I should get all products first and then filter them by a `foreach`?

Product :

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        Colors = new List<Color>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
    public virtual ICollection<Color> Colors { get; set; }

}
```

Color:

```
public class Color
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HexCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want the products that their color id is 2 or 3, These numbers are dynamic

Comment: Can you show the code that defines your classes? And could you give us some sample input and expected output? I'm sure we can help then :)

Comment: The codes are routine things, The problem is how I compare two IList in EF query, I put codes now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have the color Ids in a list `colorIds` then you can do

```
var query = from p in Products
            where p.Colors.Any(c => colorIds.Contains(c.Id))
            select p
```

This will return products having *at least* the requested colors. If you need products having *only* these colors, you can change `Any` into `All`.